# IBM Websphere ILog JRules Studio 7.1.1 Installation Failed Due to Error: Could not Java Virtual Machine

Tags: websphere, ilog, jrules

Has any one encountered the error: Could not create Java Virtual Machine error while installing IBM Websphere ILog JRules Studio 7.1.1? I have Windows 7 64 bit OS but this error could happen on any Windows machine. By default IBM ships the package for 32 bit so our installation team tried with 32 bit JDK 6 (with many minor versions) for many days but could not figure out. I have posted my own solution below. Check this out and save your life.

Answer (score 1):

You usually start installation by running JRules_V711_CZLX7ML.exe file on windows. It will extract all resources on your temp directory and you might encounter error: "Could Not Create Java Virtual Machine". Just follow these steps and it "might" solve your problem:
1. Go to your temp directory by typing "%temp%" in Start-> Run or Windows Explorer.
2. Look for directory something like: I1403739667. Go inside this directory.
3. Open command prompt and go to I1403739667/Windows/resource/jre/bin
4. Run command: java -version
5. If you see following error, go further otherwise you might have some other problems:

JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
**Error: could not load Mercury Interactive support. Please run the setup again.**
       If the problem persists please contact Mercury's Customer support.
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jpi24: The specified module could not be found.
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jvmhook(-3): JVM_OnLoad failed
**Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

1. This happens if you have installed HP Quick Test Professional which used to be Mercury before HP bought over.
2. Right click on your computer icon on desktop and look for following environment variable: IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS
3. Either rename it to IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS_DONOTUSE or delete it.
4. Try installing again.

***NOTE: I had tried to by pass this error by changing the vm property in Rule Studio.lax file to use JDK 6 32 bit installed on my windows machine and was able to install successfully but there were just too many Rules compilation errors which would not make any sense. So NEVER try to use your own JDK. You have to use the IBM JDK shipped as part of Rule Studio.***